# How do I find all .git\config files?

Tags: regex, git, powershell

I'm trying to find all `.git\config` files but I cannot figure out how to do it.

When I just use `\.git` as a pattern, it finds all directories

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Repositories -Recurse -Hidden |
    Where-Object { 
        $_.FullName -match '\.git'
    } |
    Select-Object FullName
```

but when I exapnd it to `\.git\\config$` to give me only the `config` files it yields no results:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Repositories -Recurse -Hidden |
    Where-Object { 
        $_.FullName -match '\.git\\config$'
    } |
    Select-Object FullName
```

What am I missing here? Is it because the `config` file does not have an extension?

I'm using powershell 5.1.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your regex I think - https://regexr.com/3ous1 - are you sure `$_.FullName` contains the full file path? Echo them out and make sure you are matching against what you think you are.

Comment: @Bananaapple it does because when I just use `config` as a pattern then it finds all `app.config`s and other paths containing this word, however it does not recurse over hidden directories, when I add `-Hidden` it searches only hidden directories, it's like it was mutually exclusive, either or but since only `.git` is hidden and `config` not it seems to stop at the folder level :-|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`config` isn't a hidden file, so only showing hidden files is causing it to be ignored.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | where-object fullname -match '\.git\\config'
```

Comment: Great, `Force`, couldn't they have named it _Everything_ or _All_ - one can sarach in vain :-\

Comment: Agreed. Personally, I think it's counter to the design of PowerShell to have `Get-` cmdlets hide arbitrary things based on their properties at all - where else do you have to stick a parameter "don't lie to me about what's there" ??

Comment: This will also match directories, not only files. May I propose to include a `-File` and while we are at it, also use native filtering instead of giving all entries to the pipeline? `Get-ChildItem . -Include config -File -Recurse -Force | where { $_.DirectoryName.EndsWith(".git") }`

Comment: @TToni your proposed version pulls up `libgit2\tests\resources\bad_tag.git\config` and similar wrong files because of the 'endswith' test. And `Get-ChildItem -Include` is so twitchy, I avoid it whenever possible. It behaves the same as `Get-ChildItem -Path config -recurse` because "Include qualifies the path component" and I find that always unpredictable, personally.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` doesn't hide things arbitrarily IMO. `Hidden` and `System` files are not normally part of an enumeration unless you ask for them specifically (hence, you `-Force` it to enumerate all items).